# Unable to fetch the process information using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am really new to shell scripting and I am trying to fetch the memory and cpu utilization of the processes. In the future I am going to run this script from java program so that I can get the utilization of all the child process of that java program. My script is currently looks like as

```
#!/bin/bash
# get the process Id of the program executing this shell script
ID=$PPID
echo the process id of the parent of this script is $ID

#fetch the parent of the program which executed this shell
PID=`ps -o ppid=$ID`
echo the grand parent id of the script is $PID

# traverse through all children and collect there memory/cpu utiliation information
for p in `pgrep -P $PID`; do
 top -c -n 1 -p $p  > /tmp/stat.log
done
```

Now when I am running this program I am getting following output

```
the process id of the parent of this script is 5331
the grand parent id of the script is 5331 3173 5331 6174
    top: bad pid 'Usage:'

    top: bad pid 'pgrep'

    top: bad pid '[-flvx]'

    top: bad pid '[-d'

    top: bad pid 'DELIM]'

    top: bad pid '[-n|-o]'

    top: bad pid '[-P'

    top: bad pid 'PPIDLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-g'

    top: bad pid 'PGRPLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-s'

    top: bad pid 'SIDLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-u'

    top: bad pid 'EUIDLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-U'

    top: bad pid 'UIDLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-G'

    top: bad pid 'GIDLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[-t'

    top: bad pid 'TERMLIST]'

    top: bad pid '[PATTERN]'
```

Could some one please help me.

Comment: I'm sorry but like I said you have to give a space between `ppid=` and `"$ID"`: `PID=$(ps -o ppid= "$ID" | egrep '\S+')`. Oh yes I forgot you have to add `-o`: `PID=$(ps -o ppid= "$ID" | egrep -o '\S+')`

Comment: Also if you're really using bash, `read PID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID")` may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PID=`ps -o ppid=$ID` should have had a space between `ppid=` and `$ID`.
```

Proper form (well-quoted arguments and preferring `$()` over backticks):

```
PID=$(ps -o ppid= "$ID")
```

But that would not trim-out the leading space on the output. As I had suggested, use read:

```
read PID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID")
```

Or if you like you can trim-out the space with `egrep`:

```
PID=$(ps -o ppid= "$ID" | egrep -o '\S+')
```

Using extended pattern matching may be complicated to you:

```
shopt -s extglob
PID=$(ps -o ppid= "$ID")
PID=${PID##+([[:blank:]])}
```

The `for` line could also be better done as:

```
while read -u 4 P; do
    top -c -n 1 -p "$P" > /tmp/stat.log
done 4< <(exec pgrep -P "$PID")
```

And I think you meant to redirect output to `/tmp/stat.log` as a block:

```
while read -u 4 P; do
    top -c -n 1 -p "$P"
done 4< <(exec pgrep -P "$PID") > /tmp/stat.log
```

Comment: I tried your script and now grandparentId is coming null and not printing anything, but thank you for  your help

Comment: @Ashish Which one have you tried? I just made an update on egrep. It should be `\S+`.

Comment: I have tried with both s and S, I am going to add in my question

Comment: What output do you get when you run `ps -o ppid= "$$" | egrep '\S+'`? Just on an interactive terminal. And please copy-paste.

Comment: I do not get any output for `ps -o ppid= "$$" | egrep '\S+'`

Comment: How about `read PID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID"); echo "$PID"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57438/discussion-between-ashish-and-konsolebox).